# Homework: How to split a new list into same length as input list?

Tags: python

For this assignment we were directed to write a program that will take two lists of lists and add the corresponding values together. For example, `addTables([[1,8],[2,7],[3,6],[4,5]],[[9,16],[10,15],[11,14],[12,13]])` should return `[[10, 24], [12, 22], [14, 20], [16, 18]]`.

My code is:

```
def addTables(list1, list2):
    newlist = []
    for i in range(0, len(list1)):
        for j in range(0, len(list1[0])):
            x = ([list1[i][j] + list2[i][j]])
            newlist = newlist + x
    return newlist
```

This gives me all the correct values, but displays them as one list `[10, 24, 12, 22, 14, 20, 16, 18]`. How can I preserve the structure of the original list?

Answer (score 2):

To make your code work, create intermediate lists and append them:

```
def addTables(list1, list2):
    newlist = []
    for i in range(0, len(list1)):
        sublist = []
        for j in range(0, len(list1[0])):
            x = list1[i][j] + list2[i][j]
            sublist.append(x)
        newlist.append(sublist)
    return newlist
```

Or, you can also use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> l1 = [[1,8],[2,7],[3,6],[4,5]]
>>> l2 = [[9,16],[10,15],[11,14],[12,13]]
>>> [[sum(subitem) for subitem in zip(*item)]  
     for item in zip(l1, l2)]
[[10, 24], [12, 22], [14, 20], [16, 18]]
```

Comment: You could keep even more of his/her code by saying `sublist = sublist + x`, and putting the parens back around `list1[i][j] + list2[i][j]` just like the OP